# Magento 2 .htaccess File Issue

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 only loads when .htaccess file is disabled or I rename it. But when I enable .htaccess, it give 500 error. I have tried tracking the issue in vain.

1. I tried enabling development mode to see if Magento 2 can tell the reason why, but no error message came up.
2. I constantly checked error log files, but couldn't find any error message relating to that.

Any suggestion? Anyone had this issue before? How did you resolve that?

Comment: Please check /var/log/apache/error.log or /var/log/nginx/error.log based on webserver in user and see if there is any error message.

Comment: @Mukesh Thanks for the support. There are no error log file for Apache in the /var folder. But to clarify, I have already checked the server to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on the server.